# Can gdb print the history of a global variable?

Tags: gdb, coredump

I'm checking a core dump with gdb and trying to figure out why a global value was changed from 0 to 1.
Is there a way to get the history of a global value with gdb?
Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm checking a core dump with gdb ... Is there a way to get the history of a global value with gdb?

Obviously not: GDB is not a time machine, and the `core` only contains the value of the global *at the time of crash*.

That said, if you can reproduce the crash, then you can use GDB [watchpoint](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html) to have GDB stop whenever the value changes.

Answer (score 1):

No, core dump has only process's memory dump when process terminates abnormally. Process itself does not record any history of it's variables. On the other hand you can debug live process with [gdb record and replay](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Process-Record-and-Replay.html). With record and replay you can execute the program in backward direction and therefore see the history of a global variable.